# cake php 1.3? Can I Use any model in any controller and views?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

My question is that with example. I have to show all categories of books and with checkboxes in a page which I want to be posted to next view without interacting db and there I want to store them in a hidden field in a comma separated string.

Actually I have a tab for find a book. user clicks on it and it has a list of categories of books listed which I get from categories model and used categories controller index function.
I want to post user selected categories to next view like where I will take more info regarding user filtration for books it is coming from another model and controller.

actually I want to know what I have to do I want to develop this find a book function.Should I have a model for this and a controller which they use some table for find a book or can I use any model in any controller for this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model in a controller other than its own as long as there is a relation between the two models. For example, consider the following relation:

```
"Books" Model BelongsTo "Category" Model
```

In this scenario, you can use

```
$this->Book->Category->find() inside BooksController 
as well as 
$this->Category->Book->find() inside CategoriesController
```

Coming to your case, it would help if you post your Database Schema. Nevertheless, to find a book, I assume you are using certain parameters like Categories, Genres, Publishers etc. Assuming each parameter will have it's own database table and model, your search hops would be as follows:

Page 1: List of Categories with Check boxes for Selection

- Function - Category Controller's index()
- View - /app/views/categories/index
- Passes to - Genres Controller's search()

Page 2: List of Genres with Check boxes for selection

- Function - Genre Controller's search()
- View - /app/views/genres/search
- Passes to - Publishers Controller's search()

Page 3: List of Publishers with Check boxes for selection

- Function - Publisher Controller's search()
- View - /app/views/publishers/search
- Passes to - Books Controller's results()

Page 4: List of Books filtered according to the given parameters

- Function - Book Controller's results()
- View - /app/views/books/results
- Passes to - None

I tried to be as guiding as possible, leave comment if you are still not clear how to go about searching for books. If you need help with passing data from one controller to another, read the CakePHP Manual (http://book.cakephp.org/view/57/Controller-Methods) or Google using "cakephp passing data from one controller to another" as keywords.

Hope this helps :)